# How to define language-depending content (l18n) in different language-files?

Tags: javascript, localization, ckeditor

CKEditor 4 stores language-depending content in the `lang/`-folder. I have written a custom plugin, which I do keep apart from the original CKEditor-folder. Now I would like to keep additional language-depending texts also separated from the original CKEditor-folder. I don't like to simply add the texts with their labels in the original language-files as it was done before.

http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/how-to-customize-ckeditor-with-your-own-plugins-skins-configurations/ (section "Custom Language") describes how to define own language-files, but I would like CKEditor keep loading the original language-file, and *additionally*, namely for the plugin, load additional language data.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out...

- In the plugin-folder, add a lang-folder: `myplugin/lang/`
- Add the language-files (`en.js`,`de.js` etc.)
- In the language-files, write

JS

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang( 'myplugin', 'en', {
    title: 'My Plugin',
});
```

- Under `myplugin/plugin.js`, register the language-files:

JS

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('myplugin',
{
    lang: 'de,en',
    init: function (editor) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Now you can access your locals like this: `editor.lang.myplugin.title`

The [UI Color Plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/uicolor) gives a good example of that.